# If $T\neq 0 \in End(V)$ is singular then exist $S\in End(V)$ such that $TS=0$ but $ST\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over some field $F$. If $T\neq 0 \in End(V)$ is singular then exist $S\in End(V)$ such that $TS=0$ but $ST\neq 0$

I'm getting no idea how to do it, please help someone

Comment: Hint: You can build up $S$ from a linear functional on $V$ which is non-zero on some element in the image of $T$ and a non-zero vector in the kernel of $T$. Both ingredinets exist by assumption.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find a basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_r\}$ of the image of $S$, and extend it to a basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $V$.  With respect to this basis, $S$ has a matrix of the form
$$
M = \pmatrix{A & B\\0&0}
$$
Now, consider a matrix of the form
$$
N = \pmatrix{0&C\\0&D}
$$

Comment: Why does S have a matrix of that form and T in that way?

Comment: @user425181 why indeed.  If you can't see what I'm getting at, perhaps you should ask a new question about my answer.

Comment: But can you explain me here? Please!

Comment: @user425181 I have no intention of doing so. Good luck, though.